# Accepting parameters with @Query annotation in the repository package spring boot with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, rest, get

Database used: postgreSQL

I have the following code:

```
@Query(value="select id, meta " + "from temp " + 
            "where meta @> \'{\"animal\": \"donkey\" }\'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<classDemo> findByMeta();
```

The meta column has data in the following format:

```
{
   "meta": { "animal":"dog", "type":"dirty"}
}
```

I would like to provide the value of animal as a parameter (e.g. donkey should be a parameter), so that I can extract all the records of the entered value during a get request. What can I do to the above code so that I can enter a parameter rather than a direct value?
Above code is jsonb format, present in meta column

Comment: What is the datatype of the `meta` column?  Is it json or jsonb, or is it just text?

Comment: The datatype of the meta column is jsonb

Comment: Can you please try the first example in the answer I posted below?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks
Can you also help with the additional question asked above under P.S. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeOrganek can you also show how would I accept a parameter in the query in spring boot for the form shown in P.S.? Thanks

Comment: please see section 6.2:  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Yes, I had tried that, but it doesn't work for values corresponding to a particular key in json format

Comment: `. . . where meta->'meta'->> :keyname = :keyvalue` doesn't work?  Can you show what you tried and what error you got?

Comment: According to my case, `where meta ->> 'animal' = :name` worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `meta` column is json or jsonb, then you can use this for your query:

```
select id, meta
  from temp
 where meta->'meta'->>'animal' = 'donkey'
```

If `meta` is data type text, then this will work so long as all rows in the table have valid json stored in `meta`:

```
select id, meta
  from temp
 where (meta::jsonb)->'meta'->>'animal' = 'donkey'
```

It has been a long while since I have worked in Java and even longer when it comes to Spring, but you should be able to placeholder `'donkey'` with a question mark and then `setString(1, "donkey")` on it.

Comment: Hi @Mike , any suggestions for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62921359/not-able-to-integrate-liquibase-with-my-spring-boot-project-getting-error-with ? Thanks in advance!